# What could cause PlayerPrefs to not save a string?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input-field

I have the below code. What could possibly make this not work? Other PlayerPrefs seem to work fine. The log always shows that it restores "" and yet it always saves my actual text.

EDIT:
I've just discovered that my "OnDisable" code is being called before "Start". I didn't really think that was possible, but that's the problem. So I guess my question is changing a bit...

EDIT 2:
OnDisable was being called before Start because another "Awake" function was disabling this object which apparently immediately runs OnDisable.

```cs
public InputField ModuleList;

void Start()
{
    ModuleList.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("ModuleSet", "");
    Debug.Log("Restoring " + PlayerPrefs.GetString("ModuleSet", ""));
}

public void OnDisable()
{
    Debug.Log("Saving " + ModuleList.text);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("ModuleSet", ModuleList.text);
}
```

Comment: BTW these days Save is pretty performant. In almost all cases you can just do it whenever you want. In the "old days" you would always see warnings like "only do a Save when you are not busy"  These days that issue is almost always irrelevant. You can pretty much just Save everytime you do a SetString. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call

```
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

for saving data

Make sure you do not disable you GO before Start() method being called

Comment: Weird. I've never called a Save and it's always saved. When is this necessary and when is it not?

Comment: as said in this link: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html
By default Unity writes preferences to disk during OnApplicationQuit()
so you may be didnt quit app and try to read your prefs, to save it during session you need to Save() method

Comment: you need the Save for it actually to work "between the user playing the game different times".  it will work "locally" ("during play") if you have not done a Save, which is what may have throw you off, @CodeMonkey   Quite simply, you have to Save if you want to know the values the next time the user opens the app.

Comment: Ah, interesting. In my case, I've just discovered the problem but still not the solution. My "OnDisable" is somehow being called before my "Start"!

Comment: due to execution order, it is impossible, can you give more info
link: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: That's what I thought too... So then I thought maybe it was because I indiscriminately deactivated it even though it was already inactive, but checking if it was active first didn't solve it. I must be doing something really dumb, but either way impossible is impossible, right? So what the heck? :-P

Comment: try move from start to OnEnable() method and check if it works

Comment: It does make a difference. Now it Enables, Disables, Enables, Starts, and my stuff is saved. A bit unsettling though...

Comment: the problem i think that you expect that every enabling Start method being called, but it calls only once when script is initializing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208934/discussion-between-codemonkey-and-nikolay-gonza).

Comment: I was indeed accidentally disabling my object before Start could be run. Oops!!